# Syslog Message in Multi Parts Can logstash reassemble it?

Tags: logstash

We are collecting CISE logs from our Cisco Devices. The message is arriving in multiple parts. Can logstash re-assemble them?

```
"message" => "<181>Dec 13 20:41:35 sfm-ise-psn1 CISE_Passed_Authentications 0069245712 3 1  IdentityGroup=Endpoint Identity Groups:SFDC-Assets:SFDC-AccessPoints, Step=11001, Step=11017, Step=11027, Step=15049, Step=15008, Step=15048, Step=15048, Step=15004, Step=15041, Step=15006, Step=15013, Step=24209, Step=24211, Step=22037, Step=15036, Step=15048, Step=15048, Step=15048, Step=15004, Step=15016, Step=11022, Step=11002, SelectedAuthenticationIdentityStores=Internal Endpoints, NetworkDeviceGroups=Stage#Stage#Low Impact Mode, NetworkDeviceGroups=Location#All Locations#SFDC#SFDC-Americas#SFDC-Americas-East#NY-New York NEW, NetworkDeviceGroups=Device Type#All Device Types#Switching, AuthorizationPolicyMatchedRule=SFDC Access Points, UserType=Host, CPMSessionID=000000000000000200016F9F, EndPointMACAddress=64-9E-F3-B3-5C-15, PostureAssessmentStatus=NotApplicable, EndPointMatchedProfile=Cisco-AP-Aironet-1140, DeviceRegistrationStatus=notRegistered, ISEPolicySetName=Default, AllowedProtocolMatchedRule=MAB,",
"message" => "<181>Dec 13 20:41:35 sfm-ise-psn1 CISE_Passed_Authentications 0069245712 3 2  IdentitySelectionMatchedRule=Default, HostIdentityGroup=Endpoint Identity Groups:SFDC-Assets:SFDC-AccessPoints, Stage=Stage#Stage#Low Impact Mode, Location=Location#All Locations#SFDC#SFDC-Americas#SFDC-Americas-East#NY-New York NEW, Device Type=Device Type#All Device Types#Switching, PostureStatus=Unknown, Response={UserName=64:9E:F3:B3:5C:15; User-Name=64-9E-F3-B3-5C-15; State=ReauthSession:000000000000000200016F9F; Class=CACS:000000000000000200016F9F:sfm-ise-psn1/228424214/80382355; Session-Timeout=14400; Termination-Action=RADIUS-Request; cisco-av-pair=ACS:CiscoSecure-Defined-ACL=#ACSACL#-IP-PERMIT_ALL_TRAFFIC-5165e13c; cisco-av-pair=profile-name=Cisco-AP-Aironet-1140; },",
"message" => "<181>Dec 13 20:41:35 sfm-ise-psn1 CISE_Passed_Authentications 0069245712 3 0 2015-12-13 20:41:35.925 +00:00 9534852286 5200 NOTICE Passed-Authentication: Authentication succeeded, ConfigVersionId=61, Device IP Address=10.119.68.254, DestinationIPAddress=10.1.64.13, DestinationPort=1812, UserName=64-9E-F3-B3-5C-15, Protocol=Radius, RequestLatency=7, NetworkDeviceName=Melville-3750_copy, User-Name=649ef3b35c15, NAS-IP-Address=10.119.68.254, NAS-Port=50122, Service-Type=Call Check, Framed-IP-Address=10.119.68.3, Framed-MTU=1500, Called-Station-ID=28-94-0F-34-AC-16, Calling-Station-ID=64-9E-F3-B3-5C-15, NAS-Port-Type=Ethernet, NAS-Port-Id=GigabitEthernet1/0/22, EAP-Key-Name=, cisco-av-pair=audit-session-id=000000000000000200016F9F, OriginalUserName=649ef3b35c15, AcsSessionID=sfm-ise-psn1/228424214/80382355, AuthenticationIdentityStore=Internal Endpoints, AuthenticationMethod=Lookup, SelectedAccessService=Default Network Access, SelectedAuthorizationProfiles=PermitAccess-SFDC-AP, UseCase=Host Lookup,",
```

After looking at the Aggregate Plugin i feel like i am getting closer. The message is not being assembled as a single entry yet.

```
if [message] =~ /^<181>/ {
grok {
  match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424PRI:pri}%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:time} %{IPORHOST:hostname} %{WORD:type} %{INT:taskid} %{INT:duration:int} %{INT:order:int} "}
}
    if [order] == "0" {
         aggregate {
            task_id => "%{taskid}"
            code => "map['sql_duration'] ||= 0 ; map['sql_duration'] += event['duration']"
        }
    }
    if [order] == "%{duration}" {
        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{taskid}"
            code => "event['sql_duration'] = map['sql_duration']"
            end_of_task => true
            timeout => 120
        }
    }
kv {
  type => syslog
  add_field => { "log_type" => "CISE" }
}
  }
```

Comment: It might be possible with the 'aggregate' filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html

Answer (score 1):

So whilst not related to logstash, the reason ISE truncates the logs is due to the configurable size of the syslog message. This can be configured upto 8000 bytes (for a single message) which means you do not have to use ISE Session ID for joining messages.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not entirely true. Although you can set the message size up to 8192 byes, you can still often find (particularly with the CISE_Passed_Authentications log) that you'll still get it split into two parts. Oh, and this also applies to TCP syslog. It'll be ISE splitting the messages before it passes it to some local syslog server for shipping. Having a larger UDP message size also means that packets will get fragmented, and some things may not like that as much. ... and ISE-syslog to Kafka bridge would be really handy right about now.

Answer (score 0):

I know this a bit old, but here is how I solved it in case someone is facing the same issue with ISE & Logstash

```
grok {
    match => [
        "_message", "(?:\<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}\>)?%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{IPORHOST:hostname} %{WORD:kind} %{NOTSPACE:taskid} %{INT:duration:int} %{INT:order:int} (%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE})? %{GREEDYDATA:rest}"
    ]
}       

#If this is the first part create a map and save copy of message to it 
if [order] == 0 { 
    aggregate {
        task_id => "%{taskid}"
        code => "map['message'] ||= {} ; map['message']['0'] = event.get('_message')"
        map_action => "create"
    }
} else {
    #Keep adding messages to the array until the last part is received
    # This is to ensure messages are in the correct order
    aggregate {
        task_id => "%{taskid}"
        code => "
            map['message'][event.get('order').to_s] = event.get('_message')
            event.set('message_parts', map['message'])

            if map['message'].length == event.get('duration') then
                mytags = event.get('tags')
                mytags << 'finish'
                event.set('tags', mytags)
            end
        "
        map_action => "update"
    }
}

# If we got the last part start concatenating messages else drop the event (We have a copy in map)
if "finish" in [tags] { 
    # Ruby code to convert the array to a well formatted single string
    ruby {
        code => "
            msg = ''
            a = event.get('[message_parts]')
            num = a.length

            for i in 0..num-1
                msg +=  a[i.to_s]
            end

            # set the message to the new concatenated one
            # but make sure to remove message header (PRI, timestamp, etc..) from all except first part
            event.set('message', msg.gsub(/(?<!^)<\d{3}>\w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} (.*?) (.*?) (.*?) \d+ \d+ /, ''))
        "
    }

    mutate {
        remove_field => [ "taskid", "order", "duration", "hostname", "kind", "rest" , "syslog_pri", "_message"]
    }

    grok {
        match => [
            "message", "(?:\<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}\>)?%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{IPORHOST:hostname} %{WORD:kind} %{NOTSPACE:taskid} %{INT:duration:int} %{INT:order:int} %{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE} %{INT:sequence_num:int} %{INT:msg_code:int} %{DATA:msg_sev} %{DATA:msg_class}: %{DATA:msg_text}, %{GREEDYDATA:attributes}"
        ]
    }
} else {
    # Ignore individual parts
    drop{}
}
```